# Joda Time interpreting AM/PM incorrectly

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, jodatime

I'm storing `DateTimes` as `timestamps` in my MySQL database. Joda Time is interpreting the AM/PM part of these `DateTimes` incorrectly.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1324231621L * 1000); // long pulled from DB as timestamp
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("h:mm aa z");
String timeStr = fmt.print(dt);
```

The above should result in `12:07 AM CST` but instead results in `12:07 PM CST`.

It looks like it's interpreting the hours as 24-hour based, but I'm using a lowercase "h", so I don't know why. What's the real reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got the wrong value - that timestamp is 2011-12-18T18:07:01 UTC - so it *is* 12:07pm in CST. If it was meant to be 12:07am, that would suggest that whatever was involved in getting it into the long form to start with is at fault - whether that's the process which put it in the database to start with, or the way that you've pulled it from the database.

Comment: I took a closer look at the database and noticed that the timestamp is indeed being stored as 2011-12-18 12:07:01. Obviously the problem lies in the timestamp insertion process. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.